# Android SQLite updating/inserting data won't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add or update information in an SQLite database in Android. 
The database takes a Lesson note id and a student id. If the lesson note id is 0, then a new entry is being made.

Here is what is in my Dbhelper class (for inserting, the update is fairly similar):

```
public boolean insertLessonNotes(LessonNotesData lData)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues lessonValues = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(LESSON_ID, lData.getLessonID()); // Lesson ID
    //values.put(ST_ID, lData.getStudentID()); // Student ID
    //values.put(LESSON_IMAGE_ID, lData.getImageID()); // Lesson Image ID
    //values.put(LESSON_IMAGE_NOTE, lData.getImageNote()); // Note attached to image
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_ID, lData.getLessonID());
    lessonValues.put(ST_ID, lData.getStudentID());
    lessonValues.put(DATE, lData.getDate()); // Date note added
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_READING, lData.getReadingNote()); // reading notes
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_PHONICS, lData.getPhonicsNote()); // phoncis notes
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_SPELLING, lData.getSpellingNote()); // spelling notes
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_WRITING, lData.getWritingNote()); // writing notes
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_COMMENTS, lData.getCommetns()); // comments notes
    lessonValues.put(LESSON_HOMEWORK, lData.getHomework()); // homework notes
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LESSON_NOTES, null, lessonValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

This is my lessonNotes class (where the information is entered and saved)

```
    LessonNotesData lNote = new LessonNotesData(id_To_Update, student_id, lessonDate.getText().toString(), readNote.getText().toString(), phonNote.getText().toString(), spellNote.getText().toString(), writeNote.getText().toString(), commentNote.getText().toString(), homeworkNote.getText().toString());
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int studentID = extras.getInt("studentId");
    int lessonID = extras.getInt("lessonID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LessonID is:(lessonNotes3) "+String.valueOf(lessonID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "StudentID is: (lessonNotes3) "+String.valueOf(studentID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Bundle studentId = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (lessonID != 0) {
        if (studentID > 0) {
            if (mydb.updateLessonNotes(lNote)) {
                //Update was successful
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotesList.class);
                intent.putExtra("studentId",studentID);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //Update did not complete correctly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update unsuccessful, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            if (mydb.insertLessonNotes(lNote)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Lesson note created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating lesson note! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //Return user to lessonNotesList where ListView should now show new lesson note
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotesList.class);
            intent.putExtra("studentId",studentID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to add or update anything in the system, I get this from the debug log:

```
04-02 20:02:33.925  26789-26789/com.example.ltssdyslexiaapp D/Items to add:﹕ com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotesData@42602bf8
```

Any ideas as to what this is or how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the use of a **boolean** function, if it **always returns true**? And can you post your `table creation` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its not an error at all its just a [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) output, its a DEBUG type of Log. You colud try to log the same adding line android.util.Log.d("hello","world"); to any method you want. And 'com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotesData@42602bf8' means that LessonNotesData has no toString() method and thats why you see @42602bf8 - its an instance address in memory or hash.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's a log :) 
I'm not sure why it's printing out the message to the debug log when i haven't actually got a log statement in my code that's printing out 'Items to add...'
Also, i'm still don't know why it won't add the information to the system? any ideas as to what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe that Log output comes from some 3rd party lib you are using in your project. You c this output doesn't have to be produced by SQLite or somethere around saving object to DB. It could come from any Collection class (do u use Guava?) or from some ListView if you are using new gogle's RecyclerView. Also you could do whole project search: Ctrl+Shift+F on a root folder of your project in AS/IDEA - did you searched for Log.d this way?

Comment: Also, if you are using Loaders for obtaining data from DB into the ListView this output could come from there, since u r adding a new record into DB Loader could autoupdate to add stored item into list/cursor.

Comment: It's okay, I managed to get it sorted out - It was something that I had put it, just took me a while to find it - thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ur wellcome. Here at SO we usually accepting answer to thank :)